# Get a file from CLI input

Tags: python, input, command

How do you get a file name from command line when you run a Python code? Like if your code opens a file and reads the line, but the file varies whenever you run it, how to you say:

```
python code.py input.txt
```

so the code analyzes "input.txt"? What would you have to do in the actual Python code? I know, this is a pretty vague question, but I don't really know how to explain it any better.

Answer (score 44):

A great option is the `fileinput` module, which will grab any or all filenames from the command line, and give the specified files' contents to your script as though they were one big file.

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    process(line)
```

More information [here](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html).

Answer (score 40):

```
import sys
filename = sys.argv[-1]
```

This will get the last argument on the command line. If no arguments are passed, it will be the script name itself, as `sys.argv[0]` is the name of the running program.

Answer (score 31):

Using argparse is quite intuitive:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()                                               

parser.add_argument("--file", "-f", type=str, required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Now the name of the file is located in:

```
args.file
```

You just have to run the program a little differently:

```
python code.py -f input.txt
```

Answer (score 10):

Command line parameters are available as a list via the [sys](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html) module's [argv](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html?highlight=sys.argv#sys.argv) list.  The first element in the list is the name of the program (`sys.argv[0]`).  The remaining elements are the command line parameters.

See also the [getopt](http://docs.python.org/library/getopt.html), [optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html), and [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html) modules for more complex command line parsing.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using **Linux** or **Windows PowerShell** you could **pipe " | "** it after using **cat** on input.txt file, suppose you have **input.txt** file and your **code.py** file in same directory you could use:

```
cat input.txt | python code.py
```

This will provide python input from **STDIN**. for example: if for example you're trying get names from input.txt file

input.txt has

```
john,matthew,peter,albert
```

code.py has

```
print(" is not ".join(input().rstrip().split(',')))
```

would give

```
john is not matthew is not peter is not albert
```

Answer (score 2):

I also like argparse, it's clean, simple, fairly standard, gives free error handling, and add a [-h] option to help the user.

Here is a version that do not need the named parameters, which may be annoying for a very simple script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import argparse

arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser( description = "Copy source_file as target_file." )
arg_parser.add_argument( "source_file" )
arg_parser.add_argument( "target_file" )
arguments = arg_parser.parse_args()

source = arguments.source_file
target = arguments.target_file
print( "Copying [{}] to [{}]".format(source, target) )
```

Example of how it handles errors and help for you:

>my_test.py

```
usage: my_test.py [-h] source_file target_file
my_test.py: error: the following arguments are required: source_file, target_file
```

>my_test.py my_source.cpp

```
usage: my_test.py [-h] source_file target_file
my_test.py: error: the following arguments are required: target_file
```

>my_test.py -h

```
usage: .py [-h] source_file target_file

Copy source_file as target_file.

positional arguments:
  source_file
  target_file

optional arguments:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
```

>my_test.py my_source.cpp my_target.cpp

```
Copying [my_source.cpp] to [my_target.cpp]
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what is mentioned by the already existing answers, there is an other alternative relying on the use of [Command Line Interface Creation Kit (Click)](http://click.pocoo.org/5/). Its latest stable version by the time I posted this answer is [version 6](http://click.pocoo.org/6/). The [official documentation](http://click.pocoo.org/6/) has examples on how to deal with files and pass them as command line arguments.

Answer (score -1):

Just use the basic command `raw_input`

declare input file name as string

```
inFile = ""
inFile = raw_input("Enter the input File Name: ")
```

Now you can open the file by using with `open(inFile,'w')`