# How to apply a python file execution over selected file in OSX Terminal?

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line

I am asked to create a python file abc.py, and then execute that python command over filename.txt

The code in terminal (OSX):

```
    $ python abc.py filename.txt
```

How do I write the code in the abc.py file such that it is will read "filename.txt" from the command-line, as an input in the python code?

Thanks much.

Comment: Hope, this might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033987/python-get-files-from-command-line

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is with the `sys` library.  Arguments to the python interpreter are stored in [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv)

```
import sys


def main():
    # sys.arv[0] is the path to this script (ie. /path/to/abc.py)
    filepath = sys.argv[1]
    print filepath


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you wanted to get fancier, you could use the [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) library

```
import argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('filepath')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print args.filepath
```